# Unidirectional One-to-Many Associations in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, associations

Does EF 4 support unidirectional one-to-many associations, as in:

```
public class Parent
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Something { get; set; }
  public List<Child> AllMyChildren { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Anotherthing { get; set; }
  // I don't want a back-reference to the Parent!
  // public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to compile my project with an association between Parent and Child where End2 Navigation is blank (because I unchecked the End2 Navigation Property checkbox in the Add Association dialog), I get

Error 2027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - Child.

**UPDATE:**

And what if I just have a List or similar property on Parent rather than a List?  Do I need to create a wrapping type to hold the String so that I can also hold a back-reference to Parent?

Comment: Why would you not want a back reference? Why does this bother you? That *is* the default behavior for EF, and I don't think you can turn that off - an association is always a two-way street

Comment: @marc_s: Child will never need to reference it's parent and will never be moved from one parent to another.  From a business object perspective, there's no need to reference or care about the parent.  If I add a reference to the parent, it's simply to satisfy the requirements of the persistence mechanism.  In fact Child was a struct with a few simple properties before I had to change it to a class to satisfy EF.

Comment: @Eric J: OK, from a purist standpoint, I understand your take on this. But why fight this - just be pragmatic and accept the ways your framework works and work along its lines - not against it. You'll save yourself a lot of grief.

Comment: @marc_s: I like to start as a purist (when I hold strong convictions anyhow) and then make informed decisions about where it makes sense to back away in the name of pragmatism.  If EF "just doesn't do unidirectional 1:n relationships" that's probably a reasonable compromise but I don't know that to be true yet.  If "the purists" all "accepted the way it is", EF 4 would still not support POCO's ;-)

Comment: @Eric J: yes, true :-) Guess we need both purists and pragmatists and shape the tools and their feature set together :-)

Comment: @marc_s: What if I just have a List<string> in Parent rather than a List<Child>?  Do I need to create a "container" class for the string plus back-reference to Parent?

Comment: [This screencast](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/screencast-ndash-what-rsquo-s-new-in-the-entity-data-model-designer-in-vs2010/) has a demo of how to do a one-directional association in EF 4. This should be supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Belive that this would work using Fluent API (Only way of deifning unidirectional associations)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
.HasKey(t => t.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
.HasMany(p => p.AllMyChildren)
.WithRequiredPrincipal();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh295843(v=VS.103).aspx